# Exchange 2019 IIS trying to connect to the wrong Server

Tags: exchange

The server is ASI-EX01 but exchange keeps trying to connect to to ASI-EX1

[image]

Comment: Has the server been renamed?

Comment: There was EX1 with a install of Exchange but the changed to EX01 with an install of Exchange trying to remove EX1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message in the EMS, I found a thread ***[Get-OwaVirtualDirectory failed with error "The task wasn't able to connect to IIS on the server"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92625192-ed97-460d-b23b-7a60bfa9f593/getowavirtualdirectory-failed-with-error-the-task-wasnt-able-to-connect-to-iis-on-the-server?forum=Exch2016Adm)*** about the similar issue on the OWAVirtualDirecotry, you could try to change the **Physical Path** of **PowerShell** Virtual Directory from " **%ExchangeInstallPath%\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\PowerShell** " to " **%ExchangeInstallPath%\ClientAccess\PowerShell** " in the IIS of your CAS Server:
[image]
 Then please restart IIS by clicking the "**Restart**" button and wait a while to check whether the issue still exists:
 [image]

Comment: I made the change and its still saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you encounter the same issue when you run the commands of other Virtual Directories? Were there any issues when you login EAC or OWA?

Comment: The other server was deleted so I cant access it